# Error: header values must be strings Error: advanced-http: header values must be strings ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, header

I would like to retrieve data from API to ionic. First, I was facing issue of CORS and unable to retrieve data from different devices except original port. I was trying to use http native to retrieve data on device. I have a problem of getting header from API.  I am not allowed to modify server. However, I ended up with error as below : Please guide me how to use http native in ionic.

```
 (in promise): Error: advanced-http: header values must be strings
Error: advanced-http: header values must be strings
```

I have tried with following code:

```
login(username: String, password: String) {
    if(username === undefined || username === '' || password === undefined || password === null){
      presentAlert("No username or password", this.alertController);
      return;
    }

      this.mcs.mobileBackend.setAuthenticationType(this.mcs.AUTHENTICATION_TYPES.oauth);
      this.mcs.mobileBackend.authorization.authenticate(username, password).then(
        () => {
          console.log("Test");
          this.http.get(this.mcs.mobileBackend.getCustomCodeUrl(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/lovs?code_table_name=activity_code'), {}, {headers:careheader})
      .then(data => {

        console.log(data.status);
        console.log(data.data); // data received by server
        console.log(data.headers);

      })
      .catch(error => {

        console.log(error.status);
        console.log(error.error); // error message as string
        console.log(error.headers);

      });
 }
      ).then(() => {
        console.log('test2' + username + password);
        this.getUserRole();
        this.authenticationState.next(true);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err,Headers);
        presentAlert(err, this.alertController);
      }); 

  }
getHeader(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   }
getUserRole() {
    return this.http.get(this.mcs.mobileBackend.getPlatformUrl('users/me'), {},{ }).then(data => {
      console.log(data); console.log(data.headers);
    });
  }  
 getReportList(offset: number = 0, limit: number = mcsConfig.rowLimit) {
    let queryParam = '?offset=' + (offset * limit) + '&limit=' + limit;
    //return this.mcs.mobileBackend.customCode.invokeCustomCodeJSONRequest(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/my/incidents' + queryParam, 'GET', null);
    return this.http.get(this.mcs.mobileBackend.getCustomCodeUrl(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/my/incidents'+ queryParam), {},{headers: this.getMcsHeaders()});
    }
```

The data is not shown.

Comment: can you make your question clean and simple?

Comment: because i am using native http it working great but your question is little complicated to understand.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari May I know how to use http native it ? Is it correct the way i use http native? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you are not passing url in string data type.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari my report list url is not correct? it works in port8100. but not in Emulator. How to pass url in string datatype. Thanks a lot

Comment: what you mean by report url? where it is working on port 8100. i m didn't get

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari I have used HttpClient and it works on browser -port 8100 only. When I run it on Android simulator, it won't work anymore due to CORS issue. So I try to change http native. still haven't achieved yet. I am lost.

Comment: you can't campare angular httpclient with native . http. can you simplify your question? just add one request where you getting issue.

Comment: i think you are not passing url as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my header below :

```
getMcsHeadersString() {
var cheaders = {};
for (let key in this.mcs.mobileBackend.getHttpHeaders()) {
  cheaders[key]= this.mcs.mobileBackend.getHttpHeaders()[key];
}
//console.log("STring_HeaderKey_"+cheaders['_keys']+"HeaderValue_"+cheaders['_values']);
delete cheaders['_keys'];
delete cheaders['_values'];
return cheaders;
```

}